# How to check null value from Java Method of Tibco ActiveMatrix

Tags: xpath, null, tibco, businessworks

I am having a trouble on checking null value from a Java Method component in Tibco ActiveMatrix process.

Basically, I have a Java Method component invoking java to get a billing account, if the return is null, I would like to log the searching criteria - billing account id; otherwise, I will map the object to be XML content...

The problem is while using the following in 'XPath' to check the null object in a transition (Success with condition):

- empty($Get-BA-Details/ns5:JavaMethodActivityOutput/MethodReturnValue
- count($Get-BA-Details/ns5:JavaMethodActivityOutput/MethodReturnValue)= 0
- string-length($Get-BA-Details/ns5:JavaMethodActivityOutput/MethodReturnValue) = 0

*'$Get-BA-Details' is the Java Method component.*

they all return 'false', and then try to map the java object to be XML content, which results in error while billing account is not found.

Could anyone shed some lights?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$Get-BA-Details/ns5:JavaMethodActivityOutput/MethodReturnValue=""

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Answers, especially answers with code, should be more substantial.  Explain your code a little.  Why should the OP (or anyone who reads this in the future) "try this"?  What is the code doing?

Comment: Hi Ecuevas, thanks a lot for your answer. I've tried and it didn't work. I think: $Get-BA-Details/ns5:JavaMethodActivityOutput/MethodReturnValue="" is as same as string-length(...) one.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you cannot check if the return from a Java Method activity is `null` using XPath. Instead you can create a Java Code activity that takes an `ObjectReference` as an input parameters and provides a `boolean` as an output parameter. You can then use code like to following to check if the object is `null` (`object` is the input parameter and `isnull` is the output parameter):

```
isnull = object == null;
```

I have created [BWUnit](http://windyroad.org/software/bwunit/) tests in the for this in the latest snapshot of BWUnit, which you can download from http://windyroad.org/software/bwunit/download/BWUnit-11.2.zip

The tests are located at `StackOverflow/UnitTestSuite/JavaMethodNullTestCase` in the simple example, which is found in `Examples/Simple` within the download.

Comment: Mate, thanks a lot! Haven't been here for a while for tackling other stuffs. I would like to give it a try... Thanks again!